# How do I set the title of a page in a joomla component?

Tags: joomla1.5, page-title

I have a very simple joomla component that returns database results.  It is not structured int the MVC format.   How do I code the component so I can designate a page title?  I wouldn't want to disable the existing functionality of joomla content articles.

Answer (score 4):

After some trolling on the internet, I found this code.  It works like a charm.

```
$browserbar= "anything you want";
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle($browserbar);
```

See this page for details on  other metatags:

http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-document-with-joomla-1.5-part1